# dash-plotly progress bar in browser does not show up

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have something like this in my layout.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1('Progress bar'),
    dbc.Progress(id="progress", value=50, striped=True, animated=True)
])

app.run_server(debug=True, port=9995)
```

I expect a progress bar at a value of 50% showing up in my dash app. But nothing shows up. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
app = dash.Dash()
```

Use

```
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```

Comment: dash-bootstrap-components relies on Twitter Bootstrap. To use this package, inject the Bootstrap stylesheet into your application. For convenience, links to Bootstrap CSS hosted on bootstrapcdn are included as part of the themes module:

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])